# Graphic file .eps not found though in proper directory:

Tags: graphics

I am using `graphicx` to typeset the figures for my PhD thesis. I have large files in `.eps` format. However, whenever I try to typeset the file (using pdfTeX), the console says

> "LaTeX error: File 'Figure' not found"

It is in the same directory as my `.tex` file, and the file will typeset if I create it as a `.dvi` and then convert it to `.pdf`. I would rather not do this though, because I want to use `hyperref`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm)
 Could you post  [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Comment: pdftex can not include eps files, convert them to pdf. Or you can use latex and dvips with hyperref.

Comment: Include `\usepackage{epstopdf}` after `\usepackage{graphicx}` to automatically convert `.eps` to `.pdf` and it will compile with `pdflatex`